Make bottomSheet push floating action button in Flutter
I do show a widget as persistent bottom sheet (not modal bottom sheet) with the following code:
scaffoldKey.currentState?.showBottomSheet(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white, (BuildContext context) {
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(widget.scaffoldKey.currentState!.context)
              .viewPadding
              .bottom,
        ),
        child: MyBottomSheetWidget(),
      );
    });

My problem is that I have a floating action button on the scaffold and it gets only partially pushed by the persistent bottom sheet. I would like the FAB to get pushed all the way up so that it does not obfuscate the bottom sheet.


Well, is it required to show the widget as a persistent bottom sheet? How about adding the widgets in a stack?

I'd initially recommend using a Stack instead of considering a persistent bottom sheet.
However, you could create a custom FloatingActionButtonLocation, and set its proper getOffset.
Example:
class CustomFloatingActionButtonLocation extends FloatingActionButtonLocation {
  const CustomFloatingActionButtonLocation();

  @override
  Offset getOffset(ScaffoldPrelayoutGeometry scaffoldGeometry) {
    final double fabX = scaffoldGeometry.scaffoldSize.width - 70.0;
    // Set the fabY based on the sheet height
    final double fabY = scaffoldGeometry.scaffoldSize.height - 400;
    return Offset(fabX, fabY);
  }
}

Therefore, set the floatingActionButtonLocation in the Scaffold as an instance of the CustomFloatingActionButtonLocation:
floatingActionButtonLocation: const CustomFloatingActionButtonLocation(),

